# What are the different ways to discretize continuous features?

Tags: classification, chi-squared-test, feature-selection, continuous-data, cramers-v

I'm working on classification problem. I have a set of continuous & discrete features and I'm trying to list my features in their order of significance.

- Using chi-squared test as a filter & Cramer's v measure to order my
  list
- Since Chi-Sq test can only handle discrete feature, I'm using decile binning method (10 equal frequency buckets) to discretize my continuous features.

I have also built a GLM model to validate my features selection procedure and I'm encountering following problems:

- Some variables that are not significant according to GLM are deemed as significant by chi-Sqaured test
- Also, my order of list of significant features (using Cramer's V) varies with number of buckets considered for discretization.

In such cases what is the best way discretize continuous features?